# AnyChart - Filling Stock Chart Missing Data Points

Tags: anychart

A question about filling missing data points in AnyChart stock chart.

How do you fill missing time period values in the stock chart with a horizontal line from last closing price? (A pretty standard way to display that rather than an empty space)

I figured out forced grouping plus chart.xScale('scatter') allows a linear scale when data points aren't linear.

Here is an example chart: https://playground.anychart.com/DZuFyB69

Comment: Can you elaborate please what is the aim of the required chart? Is it crucial to use scatter based scale for non-linear data? If the scatter scale is not really required, you can use default ordinal scale which will doesn't show gaps between points - https://playground.anychart.com/LKiJVpPJ

Comment: On a candlestick chart at 1 minute for example, there may be quite a few points where there is no activity but it's quite common to see a candle which is a horizontal line based on the previous closing price.

Comment: The example you gave doesn't show a linear scale on the x-axis. If there is no data for a year even then the candles are still next to each other.

Comment: Ok, now I see. In case of using scatter scale, you can fill missing points only with adding additional points manually. AnyChart doesn't provide out-of-the-box methods to implement such behaviour. You can analyze the current dataTable and add required candles which are horizontal lines based on the previous closing price.